# Find the cumulative distribution function of $X$.

Tags: probability

Player $A$ tosses a coin with sides numbered $1 \text{ and }2$. $B$ spin a spinner evenly graduated from $0$ to $3$. $B$'s spinner is fair, but $A$'s coin is not; it comes up $1$ with a probability $p$, not necessarily equal to $\frac{1}{2}$. The payoff $X$ of this game is the difference in their numbers ($A$'s number minus $B$'s). Find the cumulative distribution function of $X$.

I tried this:

$P(X=0)=(p)(\frac{1}{4})+(1-p)(\frac{1}{4})$

$P(X=1)=(p)(\frac{1}{4})+(1-p)(\frac{1}{4})$

$P(X=-1)=(p)(\frac{1}{4})+(1-p)(\frac{1}{4})$

$P(X=-2)=(p)(\frac{1}{4})$

$P(X=2)=(1-p)(\frac{1}{4})$ then

$F_X(x) = \begin{cases} 0 & x<-2
\\[8pt] \frac{p}{4} & -2\le x<-1\\[8pt] \frac{1}{4}+\frac{p}{4} & -1\le x<0 \\[8pt] \frac{1}{2}+\frac{p}{4} & 0\le x<1 \\[8pt] \frac{3}{4}+\frac{p}{4} & 1\le x<2 \\[8pt] 1 & 2\le x\end{cases}$

Am I right?? Have a nice day :)

Comment: You ought to say "$F_X(x)=\cdots$", with a subscript capital $X$ and a lower-case $x$ as the argument, and then write $x<-2$ rather than $X<-2$.  To understand the difference between the meanings of the capital and lower-case letters, think of the meaning of the expression $\Pr(X\le x)=\cdots$.

Comment: @MichaelHardy     Sorry, I did correction ; Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Evenly graduated" is an expression that points towards continuous values, but your analysis of outcomes indicates only discrete values. If discrete values of $B$ is what holds, then $X$ is a discrete random variable and intervals in its support don't really make sense. Given independence of $A$ and $B$ the joint probabilities are the product of individual probabilities, so your analysis is correct (except you forgot a $(\frac14)$ in $P(X=0)$